# How to check if a package is installed from Bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I need to check if a specific package is installed on a machine from within a Bash script.

I found something like that but I don't know how use it correctly.

```
dpkg -l | grep "ansible" | awk '{print $2}'
if [$? -eq 0]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo FAIL
fi
```

I need check, if command `dpkg -l | grep "ansible" | awk '{print $2}'` return me word "Ansible" then echo OK, else echo FAIL.

@EDIT

I think better will be command

```
dpkg -l | grep "ansible" | awk '{print $2}'
```

so this command return me two words:

```
ansible
ansible_lint
```

How should I use this bash script? If I doing something like that:

```
ansible = $?
if [$? -eq 0]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo FAIL
fi
```

that's not work, but I'm sure I doing that wrong. How can I read result from dpkg -l | grep "ansible" | awk '{print $2}' command and if I get word "ansible" script will print OK, if not print FAIL.

Comment: You have to insert blanks after '[' and before ']': `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`

Comment: Even after your edit you are still missing those spaces aroung [ ].

Comment: What do you want to do by that code? Do you want to check if a package whose name contains 'ansible' is installed? All lines printed by `dpkg -l` do not indicate installed packages. There may be removed packages, too. Note also that `dpkg -l` list much more than just package names, so you have to be more careful, if you examine its output by `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the software is installed on this way:

```
if [ "$(dpkg -l | awk '/ansible/ {print }'|wc -l)" -ge 1 ]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo FAIL
fi
```

You can't use exit code because it will be from `awk` and in this case always be 0

Comment: Great! I have one more question. Can you tell me how should it look, if I need check software is installed in pip so command pip list. If I check dpkg -l for  pip list I got that message in terminal
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.

Comment: @BElluu, please use "Ask Question" button and create new question. But in general you can replace `dpkg -l` with `pip list` to use as source the list of packages, installed with `pip`

Comment: This is bad practice in several ways: there could be several packages whose name contain string "ansible", but it could be that none of them is named "ansible". The string could be something else in the output of  `dpkg -l` than package name. Why use `awk` here, as the same could be done by `grep 'ansible' ` that may give non-zero exit code? `wc -l` is not needed in checking if a string is not null in Bash. So I wonder why this is accepted answer. I have given another answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the exact package name, you can just ask `dpkg` if it's installed with

```
dpkg -l packagename
```

For example:

```
$ dpkg -l pulsea
dpkg-query: no packages found matching pulsea
```

The exit code is also 1 (fail) if a package isn't installed, you can test for that (as seen later).

```
$ dpkg -l pulseaudio
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name               Version        Architecture   Description
+++-==================-==============-==============-=========================
ii  pulseaudio         10.0-1+deb9u1  i386           PulseAudio sound server
```

Here the exit code is 0 (success), so you can do this too

```
$ if dpkg -l pulseaudio; then echo yes;fi
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name               Version        Architecture   Description
+++-==================-==============-==============-=========================
ii  pulseaudio         10.0-1+deb9u1  i386           PulseAudio sound server
yes
```

Note the trailing "yes" above. But now since you can just use the exit code, you don't really care about dpkg's output, so ignore it with an `if` or an `&&` (AND list):

```
$ if dpkg -l pulseaudio >/dev/null; then echo yes;fi
yes

$ dpkg -l pulseaudio >/dev/null && echo yes
yes
```

dpkg can also match partial names, using asterisks, like

```
$ dpkg -l "*pulse*"
```

---

About pipes and their exit status, if you want to see if a command somewhere in a pipeline has failed you'll have to do something like examining the `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`:

```
$ false | true
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} 
1 0
```

And like `$?`, `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` changes with every command, so if you want to examine them more than once you have to save them to another variable first. In your example

```
ansible = $?
if [$? -eq 0]; then
```

`$?` has already changed by the if test, and it's probably 0 since assigning a variable like that almost always succeeds.

Comment: When testing exit code of `dpkg`, you may want to redirect standard error to null as well like this `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Another way to use exit status with pipe is by using `set -o pipefail`. See `help set` for more information.

Comment: @jarno True, that's a good tip for pipes if something in there fails. I'm pretty sure examining `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` is the only way to figure out what part failed & succeeded though, if that even matters

Answer (score 0):

To check, if package named 'pkgname' is successfully installed, use

```
if dpkg-query -W -f'${db:Status-Abbrev}\n' pkgname 2>/dev/null \
 | grep -q '^.i $'; then
    echo 'Installed'
else
    echo 'Not installed'
fi
```

See `man dpkg-query` about usage of `dpkg-query`. With `-q` option `grep` does not output anything, but exits with code 0 if and only if there is a match.

Comment: FYI, `dpkg -l` / `dpkg --list` looks like it runs `dpkg-query --list`, and `dpkg-query -W` is  "Just like the --list option  this  will  list  all packages matching the given pattern" but with a customizable format

Comment: @Xen2050 and it does not print the header lines.